# Problem with grub starting up

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

[Previously](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142016/dual-booting-windows-7-and-ubuntu-19-04), I had a problem installing Ubuntu on a Windows 7 / Ubuntu 19.04 system.  For the most part, that problem has been solved and I can dual boot between the two OS.

I am encountering a problem which I do have a work-around, but I was wondering if anyone can give an explanation to the cause of this problem (and why my "solution" works).

When I start up the computer, I get an error message that says the following:

```
Attempting boot from hard disk
Error:  No such device:  [UUID of the Ubuntu filesystem]
Error:  Unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

I figured out by accident that I can solve this problem by inserting a bootable [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) disk.  All I have to do is boot to it and get to its grub message.  I don't need to choose "Boot Repair -- Disk session" or perform any kind of repair.  Then, I take the USB drive out, restart the computer and the original grub menu appears, showing my Ubuntu and Windows systems.  I can choose either one to boot to from here.

I don't quite understand why this works.  I haven't done anything with the Boot Repair disk other than start from it.  But it does something so that the next time I boot with it, everything works.

(At this point, I could continue to use Boot Repair to attempt to "fix" it, but I worry that it will make it worse.  While my current situation is bizarre, there is a way to get my system back each and every time.  So, I'm hesitant to try something unless someone can give me a reason why it should work.)

Anyway, any suggestions would be appreciated!

Edit:

Here is the boot-repair [report](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5ZYfzXYNQj).  I can't see anything obviously wrong, but I'm not good at understanding the report.

Comment: Probably you have an older instance of grub installed in the MBR of one of your disks. One could only see that if you give us a link to boot-info-summary which you get from boot-repair. Try changing BIOS boot order to the other drive and check if this helps.

Comment: You can have boot repair create report on the internet without making any changes. do that and report the internet link here.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Thank you for the suggestion (mook765, as well)!  I've updated my question with a report.  I haven't made any changes.

Comment: Your situation sounds like this one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104855/how-to-make-grub-menu-appear-instead-grub-minimal-bash-like-in-booting/1105737#1105737

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Unfortunately, that didn't work.  I ended up not booting and getting a "No option to boot to".  However, while running Boot Repair in legacy mode, I got a warning that "The boot files of [Ubuntu 19.04] are far from the start of the disk.".  So, I created a /boot partition at the beginning of the disk, and then re-ran Boot Repair.  This still didn't fix my problem.  As before, as long as I boot into Boot Repair, my grub menu comes back (i.e., as I described in my original message).  So I haven't ruined my system...it's just a strange problem.  Thank you for the advice!

Comment: The line `=================== Final advice in case of suggested repair` followed by this line `Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sdb (ATA ST500DM002-1BD14) disk!` suggests you need to change your boot sequence to USB first, `sdb` second and `sda` last.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've tried that and that didn't work (i.e., there was no change).  After rebooting it something like 10 times this morning, I realised that when it works and when it doesn't appears to be "random".  At first, I thought it was because I inserted a `boot-repair` disk in.  But now it works even when I don't insert a disk in.  I think I need to figure out the pattern...there has to be one as it cannot be random.